# Does IDP initiated flow in SAML supports HTTP-POST and HTTP-Redirect binding, If yes the how the actual flow will be for IDP initiated flow?

Tags: saml-2.0, idp

I have to give two type of binding support to my client in the IDP initiated flow.

I have my IDP initiated code which first validated the token and gets the redirected URL then redirect to that URL.

Answer (score 0):

Only HTTP-POST and HTTP-Artifact binding can be used for IdP-initiated SSO in the Web Browser SSO profile.

How IdP (or SP)-intiated SSO is triggered is implementation specific and not defined in the SAML specification.